# How to optimize a sklearn pipeline, using XGboost, for a different `eval_metric`?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, pipeline, xgboost

I'm trying to use [XGBoost](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html), and optimize the `eval_metric` as `auc`(as described [here](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/doc/parameter.md)).

This works fine when using the classifier directly, but fails when I'm trying to use it as a [pipeline](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.15.X/sklearn/pipeline.py#L125).

What is the correct way to pass a `.fit` argument to the sklearn pipeline?

Example:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
import xgboost
import sklearn

print('sklearn version: %s' % sklearn.__version__)
print('xgboost version: %s' % xgboost.__version__)

X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)

# Without using the pipeline: 
xgb = XGBClassifier()
xgb.fit(X, y, eval_metric='auc')  # works fine

# Making a pipeline with this classifier and a scaler:
pipe = Pipeline([('scaler', StandardScaler()), ('classifier', XGBClassifier())])

# using the pipeline, but not optimizing for 'auc': 
pipe.fit(X, y)  # works fine

# however this does not work (even after correcting the underscores): 
pipe.fit(X, y, classifier__eval_metric='auc')  # fails
```

The error:
`TypeError: before_fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'classifier__eval_metric'`

Regarding the version of xgboost:
`xgboost.__version__` shows 0.6
`pip3 freeze | grep xgboost` shows `xgboost==0.6a2`.

Comment: did you try with 'roc_auc' ?

Comment: it works fine with sklearn version: 0.18
xgboost version: 0.6

Answer (score 4):

The error is because you are using a single underscore between estimator name and its parameter when using in pipeline. It should be two underscores.

From the [documentation of Pipeline.fit()](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.fit), we see that the correct way of supplying params in fit:

> Parameters passed to the fit method of each step, where each parameter name is prefixed such that parameter p for step s has key s__p.

So in your case, the correct usage is:

```
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train, classifier__eval_metric='auc')
```

(Notice two underscores between name and param)

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work either, added it to the tested options on the original question.  I think it would have worked if it were a parameter of the classifier (e.g. `nr_estimators`), but it is an argument of the fit method of that particular classifier.

Comment: I am using iris data from sklearn, and it is working fine (Not throwing any errors). Please update your scikit and / or xgboost version and try again

Comment: Interesting, can you please tell me the versions you are using? I'm using xgboost version '0.6' and  sklearn version '0.18.1'

Comment: There is definitely something strange going on. xgboost.__version__ shows something different from pip freeze for some reason. 

I changed the example to make it replicable with the iris dataset, could I ask you to see if it runs on yours? (huge thanks, even if it isn't SO policy to thank people)

Comment: I have edited your code for copy and paste. Also I tried on both Python 2.7.6 and Python 3.4.3 and it works fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138106/discussion-between-sapo-cosmico-and-vivek-kumar).

Answer (score 4):

When the goal is to optimize I suggest to use sklearn wrapper and GridSearchCV

```
from xgboost.sklearn import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
```

It looks like

```
pipe = Pipeline([('scaler', StandardScaler()), ('classifier', XGBClassifier())])

score = 'roc_auc'
pipe.fit(X, y) 

param = {
 'classifier_max_depth':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] # just as example
}

gsearch = GridSearchCV(estimator =pipe, param_grid =param , scoring= score)
```

Also you can use a technique of cross validation

```
gsearch.fit(X, y)
```

And you get the best params & the best scores

```
gsearch.best_params_, gsearch.best_score_
```